# Meaning of "finish off" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

What does "finish off" mean in this context (football/soccer)?

Everton **finished off** VIlla with a diving header from Valeri Gauvin and a goal from Chantelle Boye-Hlorkah

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a game, finishing off an opponent means winning the game from an already advantageous position, where the losing team didn't really have any hope of winning.

This phrase would usually be used when the win is decisive, i.e. the winning team's victory was by more than a small margin.